# ssrs processing time spikes

Tags: reporting-services, runtime-error, ssms

I'm developing a report in ssrs for display in a public location within the company. The report shows up-to-the-minute data on department activity, so is set to refresh every 30 seconds or so.

The problem I'm running into is that once every few hours, the report throws an error (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow) & (rsProcessingAborted). All I have to do is hit refresh in the browser (rendered in a an internet browser) and it reruns and charts along happily for a while.

After looking at the reportserver execution log, it appears that these errors coincide with a phenominal spike in processing time. On average, each time the report refreshes, processing times is 400ms~800ms, but when it spikes it goes to ~90000ms (yes, five zeroes) and then throws this error.

Being new to SSRS I am not sure where to begin looking for the root cause.

Can anyone give me pointers as to where I can start to find out what is causing the processing time to rocket like that? Data retrieval is stable at ~5000ms, and Time rendering is stable at around 200ms. It's only the processing that goes haywire.

Some background on the report and data:

Data is pretty straight forward. It's based on a view that pulls transactions from last 7 weeks. Number or records, therefore ebbs and flows each week ~ 8000 records. When select * from View is run in SSMS, query takes about 5 seconds to run. I'll work on speeding that up after I resolve this processing issue.

No parameters are used, though the view does use getdate() to figure out which records to show from base tables.

No stored procedures are used.

Report itself is comprised of 6 panes within a single tablix, none of which have to draw more than a few dozen marks ('cept one is a map of US states).

The report does have one feature that may be related, though I am not sure how. Report definition filters the dataset based on a mod 3 of the built in execution time variable, rotating the report to show "This Month", "This Week", or "Today" activity. There is an additional mod 3 on execution time which rotates visibility for the panes. The result is that each 30 seconds, a report with different combinations of charts shows up on a rotating time-frame.

Don't know if this could be a cause, but it's the only element of the report that makes it remotely fancy. Everything else about the report is actually rather straightforward/plain.

While I would love to identify and eliminate the spikes, even a mechanism to automatically refresh on error, or refresh on timeout (or something to that effect) would do the trick. I need to be able to launch the report in the morning and have it run unmanned all day without any human interaction, refreshing every 30 seconds for the duration of business hours.

Comment: I wonder if you can put your web page into a frame, then add javascript to the main page to issue a periodic refresh.  I'm not sure if you could only refresh on error vs always refresh, but it's a thought.

Comment: Do the database logs have any entries that coincide with the spikes?

Comment: Dan, can you elaborate on what you mean by entries? Are you talking about records on the base tables as in edits are locking up the table? That does give me a few ideas on the t-sql in the view, if that's not what you meant.

Comment: No, I was thinking about the performance monitoring tools in Sql Server.  If you have a DBA, ask him/her.  It may be something weird, like the temp database filling up.

Comment: Yeah, a DBA would be nice. I'm not usually querying against the production server, so this had not occurred to me, but it looks like it might have been records writing to the table that tied it up. I added a with (nocount) to my table calls in the view, and have had it running successfully for the whole afternoon without the error. It may not have been what you intended, but it did help me locate the problem. I'll mark this answered if I get through tomorrow without the error cropping up. Thanks!

Comment: apologies, meant (nolock) - nocount shouldn't do anything meaningful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a recap of the comments:

- it might be possible to push the web page into a frame, then add javascript to the main page to periodically refresh the frame.  It wouldn't fix the underlying problem, but it might help.
- it might be worth looking at the performance monitoring tools in Sql Server - it might be a database issue (temp table filling up, etc)
- You noted that adding a with (nolock) seemed to help locate the problem.

Comment: in this case, querying against a production database, it looks like it was a conflict in accessing records, so the with (nolock) did the trick. Report has been refreshing all day with no errors. Thanks for getting me on the right train of thought. On to other weird errors I'm running into and don't understand...!